# Doing workout when we are suffering from diarrhea

Tags: health-risk

Is it okay to **workout** in gym ,  when i am suffering from diarrhea ? or is it better to take **rest** that day ?

Please give me some suggestions on this....

Comment: I'd worry more about what's causing the diarrhea, and whether or not you're going to leave skidmarks on the equipment.

Comment: Regarding the close votes, this one wasn't closed and got upvotes. https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/working-out-while-slightly-ill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest that day. Hygiene concerns aside, rest will help you recover more quickly and diarrhea will dehydrate you.

If you must I would recommend some light exercise from home, but a day or two of rest is really the best choice.